Nonparametric likelihood function $\mathcal{L}_n(f) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(X_i)$ doesnt attain maximum in set of all densities
Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with distribution function $F$, and
$\mathcal{L}_n(f) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$ it's likelihood function. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all possible distributions. How can I show that $\mathcal{L}_n$ doesn't attain a maximum in $\mathcal{F}$? My initial thought was showing that for any $f$, there exists another density $g$ such that $g(x_i) > f(x_i) \  ,i=1,\dots, n$, but I'm not sure how to prove this. Is it as simple as defining $g(x_i) = f(x_i) + \epsilon$ and then for some $y_1, \dots, y_n$ defining $g(y_i) =  f(y_i)-\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ and $y_i$ chosen carefuly so that $g \geq 0$?
